# Is it possible to launch a new Docker container in the network of an already running container?

Tags: docker

Can I start a new Docker container, from the command line, in the same network of an already running container?

The original container was not run with a defined network (no `--network` parameter).

Here is an example of what I would like to happen:

```bash
# Start a 1st container named host1.
$ docker run --name host1 -dit alpine ash
…

# Start a 2nd container and open a shell.
$ docker run -it --rm alpine

# Try to ping the 1st container from inside the 2nd container.
/ ~ ping host1
ping: bad address 'host1'
```

How could the second command be changed so that the second container sees `host1`?

Comment: I'd suggest `docker network create`ing a new named network, deleting the existing container, and then creating both containers on the new network.  I'd avoid using the "default bridge network" (with no `docker run --network` option), since it has some limitations like inter-container DNS not working by default.

Comment: @DavidMaze Is that the only option? My goal is to avoid one additional command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I start a new Docker container, from the command line, in the same
> network of an already running container?

Yes. Actually, in your example, **you're probably already doing just that:** you created both containers in the [default `bridge` network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-the-default-bridge-network) - even though you didn't specify `--network`, Docker created them in this default network.

You can't use `host1` hostname to reach your first container from your second container because [DNS resolution in the default `bridge` network](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) won't resolve container's hostname in this default network. (it would work in a non-default network specified with `--network` because [DNS resolution is different](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge))

However you can reach it directly via it's IP, for example:

```
# Start a 1st container named host1.
$ docker run --name host1 -dit alpine ash

# Get host1 IP
$ docker inspect host1 --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'

172.17.0.2

# Start a 2nd container and open a shell.
$ docker run -it --rm alpine

# Try to ping the 1st container from inside the 2nd container.
# Won't work with hostname
/ ~ ping host1
ping: bad address 'host1'

# Will work with IP
/ ~ ping 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.322 ms
...
```

It looks like that what you really want is to contact container by their hostname in default `bridge` network. Your question may be reformulated as

*Can I start a container in the default `bridge` network and resolve its hostname from another container in the same network?*

You can specify `host1` IP with `--add-host` such as:

```
$ docker run -it --rm \
    --add-host host1:$(docker inspect host1 --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}') \
    alpine

/ ~ ping host1
PING host1 (172.17.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.322 ms
```

Which will pass `host1`s IP as available hostname to new container

---

That being said, you'll probably be better of using a custom network, for example:

```
docker network create mynetwork
docker run --name host3 -dit --network mynetwork alpine ash
docker run -it --network mynetwork alpine ping host3
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. if you don't specify a network the default network is used. So starting a new container without specifying a network will put it on the default.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to clarify my question with a practical example.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You have to add host resolution to `/etc/hosts` in each container:

```
# docker exec -it host2 ash -c "echo `docker inspect host1 --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'` host1 >> /etc/hosts"
# docker exec -it host2 ping -c 1 host1
PING host1 (192.168.128.2): 56 data bytes
```